# Download Manager Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

i am running a Art website where designers can find free design stuff and i want to track my downloads which are uploaded on another server.

For example

`www.abc.com` is my website and files are hosted on `files.abc.com`

I am using wordpress and found many plugins for it and the best plugin was Wp download manager. but its not free. Can any one please help me with it

Comment: How do you want to track? Analytics?

Answer (score 1):

use database for this.
create download.php file and simply insert data into database and redirect visitor to files.abc.com

your download link will look like www.abc.com/download.php?id=10